# Colocar setLoading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hola les quiero pedir ua ayuda, tengo que colocar el setLoading para que el spinner funcione y no tengo idea donde ponerlo, alguien me podria ayudar? Gracias!!!

Comment: Por cierto cuál es el punto de declarar la funcion `printInstruments` si la vas a llamar ahí mismo?

Comment: Hola, lo ideal es que no solo pongas imagenes de tu codigo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/756

Por otro lado, lo que podrias hacer es establecer que `loading` verdadero para que desde un inicio el spinner aparezca y cambiar el valor a falso despues de la llamada a `getDocs` incluso antes o despues de llamar a `printInstruments` que es cuando tu informacion esta lista.

Comment: @Isaac el problema con setear `loading` a `true` solo al principio es que si `categoryId` cambia, el callback de useEffect se ejecutaría de nuevo pero `loading` quedaría en `false` así que no se mostraría el spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setLoading(true)` antes de `getData()` y `setLoading(false)` luego de `setData()`. De todos modos no estoy 100% seguro de que funcione correctamente con funciones asincronas. Es posible que tengas que reescribir la funcion getData

Comment: Hola gracias por responderme, lo pude solucionar de la sigiente manera:
puse setLoading(true); como digiste antes del getData() y un setLoading(false) antes del printIntrument y funcionó

Comment: Óptimo. Ahora que lo dices era obvio que el `setLoading(false)` tenía que estar dentro del callback para resolver el problema de que la función es asncrónica